# Vuex Getters and Typescript errors

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have a project which uses Vuex and the Composition API. I have enabled typescript and I have a component which needs to pull a boolean value from a getter in my store module like so:

```
const flag = computed(() => store.getters['test/flag'])
```

the code works fine while I’m developing, but if I try to build it, I get the following typescript errors:

> 106:33  error  Unsafe member access ['test/flag'] on an any value
> @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access 106:33  error  Unsafe
> return of an any typed value
> @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return

How do I configure the store to use getters with typescript?

Comment: This is linter error. It's obviously incompatible with a way getters are supposed to be used with composition API. So disable it.

Answer (score 4):

By default, Vuex stores are not type safe. You'll need to use a third party library to solve that.

Personally, I suggest using [typed-vuex](https://typed-vuex.roe.dev) which works like a charm and only use wrappers around your existing vanilla store.

Then you can use your store like `this.$accessor.test.flag` with types.

> Note: you can also just disable the eslint rule, it's up to you :)

Comment: According to https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1756 getters are currently typed as any, which is why the linter is flagging it.